# How to limit STUFF function within CTE for removing character before recurring word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation

A follow up question for [Replace a recurring word and the character before it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079713/how-to-replace-a-recurring-word-and-the-character-before-it-in-mssql)

Credit to @Larnu for the following code, how would this code be modified to not produce a null value if there is no longer a character before a recurring word, "[BACKSPACE]". I believe the null value is occurring because the `CHARINDEX()` functions are producing a negative value when there is no longer a character before the recurring [BACKSPACE] word. The solution would need to be compatible with SQL Server 2008.

The ultimate goal is for anywhere that there is a [BACKSPACE], IF there is a character before [BACKSPACE], remove it; otherwise, don't try to remove the character before.

```
DECLARE @inputString NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @inputString = 'Word[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]sgred[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]SecondWord';

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT V.YourColumn,
           STUFF(V.YourColumn,CHARINDEX('[BACKSPACE]',V.YourColumn)-1,LEN('[BACKSPACE]')+1,'') AS ReplacedColumn,
           1 AS Iteration
    FROM (VALUES(@inputString))V(YourColumn)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.YourColumn,
           STUFF(r.ReplacedColumn,CHARINDEX('[BACKSPACE]',r.ReplacedColumn)-1,LEN('[BACKSPACE]')+1,''),
           r.Iteration + 1
    FROM rCTE r
    WHERE CHARINDEX('[BACKSPACE]',r.ReplacedColumn) > 0)
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       r.YourColumn,
       r.ReplacedColumn
FROM rCTE r
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.YourColumn ORDER BY r.Iteration DESC);
```

The desired output is `'SecondWord'`

Comment: @Charlieface if you run the above code, you will see that the "ReplacedColumn" will output as NULL. This I believe is because the above code is doing its job of replacing the character before [BACKSPACE], but once it runs out of a character before [BACKSPACE] such as the beginning of the string it will produce a NULL value.

Comment: @Charlieface with reference to your comment to John, questions should be stand alone, not dependent on other questions. So if its required to read the other question to understand this one, then this one isn't clear enough.

Comment: I don't understand why the above would be expected to return `'Word SecondWord'` I would expect `'SecondWord'`.

Comment: It's altogether not working like you think. Take away the `top 1` and you will see. Each iteration just takes off one character before, and at some point the backspaces merge because `sgred` only has 5 characters and 7 backspaces after it. So @Larnu is right: what do you want to happen here?

Comment: Also, yes I asked you to post a new question here as well, as you moved the goal posts, what  @DaleK says is still true; include *all* the information needed here.

Comment: Could you have a string like `'abc[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]def[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]Hello'`?

Comment: @Larnu, I do apologize, I have updated my desired output and tried to add enough standalone detail for the question. Yes you could have a string as you posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need a `CASE` check to see if you are at the beginning of the string, in which case you don't want the position before, as that is 0.**

Some other improvements I would make to this code: `LEN` could be calculated once, and we could store the `[BACKSPACE]` value in a variable also

```sql
DECLARE @inputString NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @inputString = 'Word[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]sgred[BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]SecondWord';

DECLARE @bspace nvarchar(50) = '[BACKSPACE]';
DECLARE @len int = LEN(@bspace);

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT V.YourColumn,
           STUFF(V.YourColumn,CHARINDEX(@bspace,V.YourColumn)-1,@len+1,'') AS ReplacedColumn,
           1 AS Iteration
    FROM (VALUES(@inputString))V(YourColumn)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.YourColumn,
           CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@bspace,r.ReplacedColumn) = 1
             THEN STUFF(r.ReplacedColumn,1,@len,'')
             ELSE STUFF(r.ReplacedColumn,CHARINDEX(@bspace,r.ReplacedColumn)-1,@len+1,'')
           END,
           r.Iteration + 1
    FROM rCTE r
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@bspace,r.ReplacedColumn) > 0)
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       r.YourColumn,
       r.ReplacedColumn
FROM rCTE r
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.YourColumn ORDER BY r.Iteration DESC);
```

Comment: Righto. I've left the spacing in the original code, the code I added has spacing

Comment: You need a case... in which case - bom bom! lol